# change value of default template in handlebars

Tags: html, node.js, express, routes, handlebars.js

i have created a template using handlebars.i need to change certain variables after of if user is logged in.

that could be done by passing the value to variable when rendering the page.

but i need to change the value of my main template that is the default layout.

here is the part of the code

```
<a class="nav-link nav-link-white dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                           {{account or user name here}}
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down ml-2"></i>
                        </a>
```

here is my app file

```
    var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var passport = require('passport')
var session = require('express-session')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var env = require('dotenv').config()
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
var path = require("path")  //added

app.use(express.static('public'));


//For BodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// For Passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'key', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions


//For Handlebars
app.set('views', './app/views')
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main", layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname,"app/views") }));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //res.send('Welcome to Passport with Sequelize');
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html')); //added
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
    res.render('dashboard');
});

//app.get('/bags', function (req, res) {
//    res.render('bags');
//});


//Models
var models = require("./app/models");


//Routes
var authRoute = require('./app/routes/auth.js')(app, passport);


//load passport strategies
require('./app/config/passport/passport.js')(passport, models.user);


//Sync Database
models.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
    console.log('Nice! Database looks fine')

}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, "Something went wrong with the Database Update!")
});



app.listen(5000, function (err) {
    if (!err)
        console.log("Site is live"); else console.log(err)

});
```

this is my route

```
 var authController = require('../controllers/authcontroller.js');

module.exports = function (app, passport) {

    app.get('/signup', authController.signup);


    app.get('/signin', authController.signin);


    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/signup'
    }
    ));

    app.get('/bags', authController.bags)

    app.get('/productpage', authController.productpage)

    app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, authController.dashboard);


    app.get('/logout', authController.logout);


    app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/signin'
    }
    ));


    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        res.redirect('/signin');
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi @Zuhaib, welcome to StackOverflow! This questions seems to have _a lot_ of information packed in it, but it can probably be boiled down a bit. Please read up on [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to create a [**Minimal, Complete and Cerifiable Example (MCVE)**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Once you edit this post, I'm sure we'll be able to help you!

Comment: boiled down to best i could do..sorry for not following the guidelines...

Comment: i think this should be done something like this
`var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
    defaultLayout:'main',
    helpers: {
      year: function() {
        return new Date().getFullYear();
      }
    }
});`
but how to check if user is logged in here.

Comment: isLoggedIn is the function tat checks if the user is logged in..